# Creating deb package that depends either on A or B package

Tags: dpkg, dependencies, deb, packaging

I created a deb package that has:

```
Package: foo
Depends: libssl1.0.1 (>= 1.0.1)
```

This works fine on `trusty` or `jessie` but it won't work on `zesty` since `libssl1.0.2` is a different package than `libssl1.0.1`.

Is there a way to specify on the deb package that either depends on `libssl1.0.1` OR `libssl1.0.2`? or is there a workaround other than creating two distinct deb packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the Debian Policy Manual, Chapter 7: *Declaring relationships between packages*](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html):

> In the `Depends`, `Recommends`, `Suggests`, `Pre-Depends`, `Build-Depends`,
>   `Build-Depends-Indep` and `Build-Depends-Arch` control fields of the
>   package, which declare dependencies on other packages, the package
>   names listed may also include lists of alternative package names,
>   separated by vertical bar (pipe) symbols `|`. In such a case, that part
>   of the dependency can be satisfied by any one of the alternative
>   packages.
>
> [...]
>
> For example, a list of dependencies might appear as:
>
> ```
> Package: mutt
> Version: 1.3.17-1
> Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.1), exim | mail-transport-agent
> ```

So, presumably:

```
Depends: libssl1.0.1 (>= 1.0.1) | libssl1.0.2
```

Comment: If you want your package to depend on A or ( B and C) use
A | B, A | C . For example
qt5-default (>= 5.2.1) | qtbase5-dev, qt5-default (>= 5.2.1) | qtchooser (>= 55-gc9562a1-1~)